# How do I subscribe to or enable my Azure app for Bing Ads?

Tags: php, azure, bing-ads-api

I'm sending the user to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope=https://ads.microsoft.com/ads.manage%20offline_access&client_id=myappid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://asdlkfjalsdjkf.com/callback`

and after they consent Microsoft redirects to my callback url with the following error:

```
error: invalid_client
error_description: AADSTS650052: The app needs access to a service (\"https://ads.microsoft.com\") that your organization \"XYZ org\" has not subscribed to or enabled. Contact your IT Admin to review the configuration of your service subscriptions.
Trace ID: xxxxxxxxx
Correlation ID: xxxxxxxxx
Timestamp: 2019-12-03 22:39:00Z
error_uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=650052
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

I'm using the [Bing ads sdk](https://github.com/BingAds/BingAds-PHP-SDK) and I'm following this [example](https://github.com/BingAds/BingAds-PHP-SDK/blob/master/samples/WebAuthentication/OAuth2Callback.php)

Comment: Did you use the Microsoft Advertising user account to consent? Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/get-started?view=bingads-13

Comment: WOW! I can't believe I didn't know this or even try this. Post it as an answer and i'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the Microsoft Advertising user account to consent. Refer to [this guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/get-started?view=bingads-13)e for more details.